# Javascript Reference function from fat arrow function, or how to trigger function every X sec

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, object, ecmascript-6

i mainly do java, and have done for long time.

But for now im trying to do a simple frontend with react.

But i cant figure how i would call function from outside the `class Home extends Component`

```
function queryJobTime () {

    console.log('activated');
    queryJob()
    console.log(active)
}
```

which is outside the

```
class Home extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {...}
   } 

   queryJob = () => { ..long axios method.. }

   ..many lines omitted...

   setInterval(function () { queryJobTime(); }, 60);

}
```

If i remove all the lines but `console.log('activated');` it will indeed log activated constantly. But thats kinda useless, what i need is to query endpoint and proceed if results are available.

**So i want to call queryJob = () => {} (axios fat arrow something, inside class Home) from function queryJobTime()**

```
function queryJobTime()
```

should trigger the axios POST, every X sec, to find if long-long-long running server task is completed.

Comment: Is the function in the same file but outside the component or in another file all together?

Comment: If `queryJobTime` is outside of the class it will not have access to `queryJob` because that is a non-static class method. You need to move the logic of `queryJobTime` into the class then call `queryJob` as `this.queryJob`

Comment: How would you do that in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `new Home` (the props argument is only required if `queryJob` requires the props):

```
function queryJobTime() {
    console.log("activated");
    new Home("prop").queryJob();
    console.log(active");
}
```

Comment: Whelp, this works. One more question. how do i now stop the querying? i had clearInterval(interval) when autoQuery if goes to complete, but now interval is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You could run `queryJob` on `componentDidMount` method and use recursion with `setTimeout` to repeat calling it as long as the promise is not resolved.

## [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/jx8r6tbu/)

```
let completed = false;
setTimeout(() => completed = true, 3000);

function queryJobTime() {
  console.log('activated')
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (completed) resolve("Completed");
    else reject()
  })
}

class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    completed: false
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.queryJob()
  }

  queryJob = async() => {
    try {
      const res = await queryJobTime()
      this.setState({completed: true})
      console.log(res)
    } catch (err) {
      setTimeout(() => this.queryJob(), 300)
    } 
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.completed) return <div> Completed </div>
    else return <div> Not Completed </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( 
  <Home /> ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```